# ShotCut does not start

Tags: drivers, opengl

```
No appenders registered with logger
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> language "hu_HU" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> deinterlacer "onefield" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> external monitor "" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> GPU processing false 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> interpolation "nearest" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> video mode "" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> realtime true 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> Starting Shotcut version 18.03.06 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> Linux version 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> number of logical cores = 4 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> locale = QLocale(Hungarian, Latin, Hungary) 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> install dir = "/snap/shotcut/21/Shotcut.app/bin" 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> device pixel ratio = 1 
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[Warning] <> Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::changeTheme> begin 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::changeTheme> end 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::MainWindow> begin 
[Fatal  ] <> Could not initialize OpenGL
Aborted (core dumped
```

My terminal when i type sudo shotcut

Comment: i have the same problem on ubuntu 18.04.  did you find a solution?

Comment: nvidia?  https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1763717